# viewWillAppear called again and again

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear

Apple says in the `viewWillAppear` [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> This method is called before the receiver’s view is about to be added
>   to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for
>   showing the view.

What does this sentence means

> before any animations are configured for showing the view.

I am actually expecting the `viewWillAppear` to be called when the view is added in to the view hierarchy but when i come back from the background app to the foreground it also calls `viewWillAppear` when the view controller is already in the view hierarchy. Does it have to do some thing with the sentence

> before any animations are configured for showing the view.

also the similar thing happens if i switch the tabs or some `modal view controller` is dismissed from my view.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour.

Comment: does bringing up the control center does not counted as the current visible view controller is going away? So does that mean that when ever the view will become visible this method will be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most classic and reliable method for the purpose you need is `viewDidLoad`.

`viewWillAppear`/`viewWillDisappear` and similar methods are designed to be called multiple times, `viewDidLoad` - only once, when the view first loads itself on the navigation stack, for example.

Comment: Yeah i know they will called once but what does exactly "before any animations are configured for showing the view." line means?

Comment: @Madu probably it means that this method is called before the VC is visible to the user, thus no animations are configured for showing it.

Comment: @Madu it means that everything you put here will be done before the view starts to slide on to the screen (if animated). Changes made to the view here will be visible immediately upon presentation. If you put code in `viewDidAppear` instead, those changes will be visible _after_ the view has already appeared on the screen.